# How to change of ionic-icon based *ngFor and firestore

Tags: firebase, web, ionic2, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have one collection called **cards**

```js
  export interface Card {
    category: string;
    description: string;
    title: string;
    url_articulo: string;
    url_img: string;
    source: string;
    date: any;
  }
```

and its subcollection called **likes** with userId as id and this structure for each doc (it's part of cards):

```js
export interface Like {
    like: boolean;
    userId: string;
    idcard: string;
  }
```

Any of this cards contain subcollection likes this collection is created when user click in **ion-icon**

home.html

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let card of cardsArray; let i = index">
 <img style="padding:15px" (click)="openUrl(card.url_articulo)" [src]="card.url_img | sinfoto" onError="this.src='assets/img/noimage.png'" />
      <ion-card-content>
    ......
<ion-icon (tap)="saveCard(card, card.id, i)" color="danger" style="font-size:38px" class="show" [name]="condition ?  'heart' : 'heart-outline'"></ion-icon>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I want to change **ionic-icon** based in like (Boolean) I try to retrieve all collection a its subcollection with a query but it is not supported in firestore, now I can change state in firestore when user clic on ionic-icon like this.

```js
   saveCard(card, idCard, index) {
 
 //referecia para escuchar cambios en nuestro doc Like
    const refFav: AngularFirestoreDocument<Like> = this.firestore.doc<Like>('cards/' + idCard + '/favs/' + this.uid);

  // referencia para nuestro documento liked users
    const refUser:AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.firestore.doc('users/'+this.uid+'/favs/'+ idCard);
    
    
    // verificamos si la referencia existe.
    const getrefav = refav.get();
    getrefav.then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
         this.streamFav = refFav.valueChanges();
        const sus = this.streamFav.subscribe(data => {

          this.LikeArray = data;
          console.log(' like array', data);
          
          
          if (this.LikeArray.like == true) {
              refav.update({ like: false, idcard: idCard });
              index
              refUser.delete();
              sus.unsubscribe();
          } else {
            refav.update({ like: true,  idcard: idCard });
              refUser.set(cardObject);
              sus.unsubscribe();
          }
        })
      } else {

        // objeto like
        const likeObject = {
          like: true,
          userId: this.uid
        }
        refav.set(likeObject);
      }
    }) 
 
   }
```

But no ion-icon in DOM

Comment: I'm not sure if im understandign your question, but you could make two Icon sets and use *ngIf when one is clicked?

Comment: Thanks man for your reply after of a lot thinking,  I  solve it, I had to iterate with  cycle for collection cards and its subcollection favs. and push  true or false in another array  if reference exist in firestore, if not push false,  then based in index of *ngFor in DOM show icon binding its index of *ngFor to second array. If you want a snippet of code reply me.